# I sent and received data between viewControllers using rxswift, but the text of the button on the receiving side does not change

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

It is the partial of code
I can post the full code if you want, but it's too long...

```
final class FirstVC: UIViewController {

    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView

    private lazy var scrollBackgroundView: UIView

    private lazy var writeView: UIView

    private lazy var categoryStackView: UIStackView

    private lazy var titleCategoryDateStackView: UIStackView

    **private lazy var categoryButton: UIButton** = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("항목", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        button.setTitleColor(.appColor(.baseGray), for: .normal)
        button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(categoryButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    let viewModel = FisrtViewModel()
    func bind(_ viewModel: FirstVC) {
        viewModel.getCategory
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] category in
                guard let self else { return }
                self.categoryButton.setTitle(category, for: .normal)
                self.categoryButton.isEnabled = true
                self.categoryButton.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.categoryButton.setNeedsLayout()
                print(self.categoryButton.titleLabel?.text)
                print(self.categoryButton.titleLabel)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}


final class FisrtVM {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    let getCategory: Signal<String>
    let giveCategory = PublishSubject<String>()
    
    init() {
        getCategory = giveCategory
            .map({ str in
                print("giveCategory", str)
                return str
            })
            .asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: "Error")
    }
}

final class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let viewModel = SecondVM()
    let firstVC = FirstVC()
    
    let category = ["categoryData", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"]

    func bind(_ viewModel: SecondVM) {
        firstVC.bind(viewModel.firstVM)
        
        categoryTableView.rx.itemSelected
            .asObservable()
            .map { [weak self] indexPath -> String in
                self?.dismiss(animated: true)
                print("itemSelected", self?.category[indexPath.row])
                return self?.category[indexPath.row] ?? ":("
            }
            .bind(to: viewModel.categorySelected)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)   
    }
}

final class SecondVM {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let firstVM = FirstVM()
    
    let categorySelected = PublishSubject<String>()
    
    
    init() {
        categorySelected
            .map({ str in
                print("categorySelected",str)
                return str
            })
            .bind(to: writeViewModel.giveCategory)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

itemSelected Optional("categoryData")

categorySelected categoryData

giveCategory categoryData

Optional("categoryData")

Optional(<UIButtonLabel: 0x7fd310e1c2d0; frame = (0 -10; 0 20); text = 'categoryData'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x6000028b4230>>)

Confirmed that the data is coming into the button
But the view doesn't update... why?...

I searched for various articles and tried each one.
I changed the code dozens of times... but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your SecondVC and SecondVM objects both make entirely new instances of FirstVC and FirstVM rather than using the ones that are already created. Any effects that happen on the first VC that is actually being presented will have no effect on the instances that SecondVC has.

The only thing that the FirstVC should be passing to SecondVC is the Observable that emits the values that SecondVC needs. SecondVC does *not* need the entire FirstVC instance.